# Can't create sql query

Tags: sql

I have two tables

1) Genres with columns: id, name 
2) Tracks with columns: genre_id, name

I need select 2 columns: name of genre and count tracks with this genre. Can you help me?

```
select g.name, count(t.genre_id)
from genres g, tracks t 
group by t.genre_id
having g.id = t.genre_id
```

Comment: can you show your code please

Comment: you have no `group by` clause...

Comment: Have you looked at `JOIN` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g.name,
       COUNT(t.genre_id)
 FROM genre g
 JOIN tracks t ON t.genre_id = g.id
 GROUP BY g.name
```